# What's causing ffmpeg to fail with such large "out of range" errors?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video camera I used to be able to generate short clips from, using an ffmpeg command like this: `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i INPUT.mp4 -t 00:00:30 -codec copy OUTPUT.mp4`

This was previously tested and working, however lately the command fails with newly created video files and I see errors like this with un-playable video output:

```
[mp4 @ 0x55f1ac7e71c0] Application provided duration: -9223372036854775808 / timestamp: -9223372036854775808 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x55f1ac7e71c0] pts has no value
```

Why are the duration and timestamp values such high (negative?) values?

The source video files play normally and I can re-encode them and get decent quality output. I can also use `-vcodec copy -an` to suppress the audio track and while I see the same errors in the terminal output, it does output playable video clips without sound.

I'm using ffmpeg version 4.4 with Fedora 34 Workstation if that matters.

Here's the command with complete console output:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i GHAG0912.MP4 -t 00:00:10 -codec copy OUT.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' -I/usr/include/rav1e' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librav1e --enable-libsmbclient --enable-version3 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-vulkan --enable-libglslang --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-lto --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GHAG0912.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
    firmware        : HD8.01.02.50.00
  Duration: 00:05:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 55758 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 55506 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 15:10:15:12
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 15:10:15:12
  Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD  
      timecode        : 15:10:15:12
  Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 44 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
  Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 9 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
[mp4 @ 0x557a365f5180] Application provided duration: -9223372036854775808 / timestamp: -9223372036854775808 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 0x557a365f5180] pts has no value
Output #0, mp4, to 'OUT.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    firmware        : HD8.01.02.50.00
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 55506 kb/s, 0.04 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AVC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 15:10:15:12
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-05-14T15:10:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 15:10:15:12
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/frame=  268 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   72885kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=59739.3kbits/s speed= 301x    
video:72629kB audio:248kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.010705%
```